# DataStax Enterprise debian/ubuntu installation error

Tags: ubuntu, datastax-enterprise

```
$sudo apt-get update

Fetched 1,499 kB in 13s (107 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages 401 Unauthorized

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

Original Post: http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/datastax-enterprise-installation-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  are  giving invalid credentials used in the datastax.sources.list file.

To add a DataStax repository file called /etc/apt/sources.list.d/datastax.sources.list:

```
 $ echo "deb https://dsa_email_address:password@debian.datastax.com/enterprise stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/datastax.sources.list
```

where dsa_email_address and password are the DataStax Academy account credentials you created on the registration page.

**Attention:** Depending on your environment, you might need to replace @ in your email address with %40 and escape any character in your password that is used in your operating system's command line. Examples: ! and \|.

Help: [Cassandra installation docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/install/installDEBdse.html)

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by invalid credentials used in the datastax.sources.list file created by the user.